# QGIS 3.22.8 LTR - problems with WMS services

Tags: qgis, web-service

We have upgraded to QGIS version 3.22.8 LTR. But in this version we have problems with some WMS services.
The connection to the service is established, the layer can be loaded, but it does not show any data. Only after repairing the data source and referencing the same service again, the data is displayed.
Such problems did not occur in previous versions, for example QGIS 3.4.8 or 3.22.4.
In newer versions, such as QGIS 3.24.3, the service works without problems. However, we need the version 3.22.8 LTR described above and we cannot simply switch.

Example:
https://geodienste.sachsen.de/wms_geosn_dtk-pg-color/guest

If I leave QGIS in default settings, i.e. CRS: EPSG 4326 then the service is loaded correctly. However, I need CRS: EPSG 25833 as default and with that it only works as described above.

Comment: Have you tried with a clean, new profile?

Comment: As described above, I tried it with the default settings and it works. But in all other QGIS version it works also with changed settings and I have to use the CRS EPSG:25833. Unfortunately, the default CRS EPSG:4326 does not do much for me.

Comment: As soon as I set the CRS EPSG 25833 as default CRS for projects the loading of services does not work anymore

Comment: Maybe it is a translation issue but please do really try with a completely new profile, not just with (re-)setting some settings to their default values.

Comment: I have already tried. Settings ==> User Profiles ==> New Profile...
Unfortunately the same result

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! :)
Then I would say it is a case for https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139037/discussion-between-joe-gerner-and-bugmenot123).

Comment: Sorry, don't have the resources for 1-on-1 support on this.